# What is the best businessmodel when using NHibernate to access the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm starting to use NHiberante as a dataaccess tier.
I'm used to work with the repository model as a business model.

This means, my domain model (not really a tier), my asp.net application tier, my repository tier which finally uses my dataaccess tier.

But with what I've learned by now (on NHibernate) I know that many logic is done within an ISession so I was wondering if NHibernate could be used within the repository tier.

Or perhaps there are even better ways to use NHibernate. Does anyone know where I could find a propriate example of how to use NHibernate in an webapplication?

Cheers,
M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[S#arp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/MainPage.ashx) is a complete example or a Web architecture using NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nhibernate with Linq extension. By using Linq, you can write your logic in your service layer and repository only get items IQuerable.